# How does MySQL compare datetime to date?

Tags: mysql, date-comparison

Can someone please explain how comparisons between `date` and `datetime` are evaluated? When a time is specified on one side but not the other, what is it comparing against? For instance:

```
SELECT '2018-01-01 00:00:00' > '2018-01-01'
```

is `1`, but

```
SELECT '2018-01-01' > '2018-01-01'
```

is `0`

I thought that without a time specified the dbms would assume `00:00:00` but apparently that is not the case. Why does my first comparison above evaluate as true while the second does not?

Comment: Those aren't dates, they're strings.

Comment: @ceejayoz - correct.  But they could easily be `date` and `datetime` typed columns and the example would hold.  Are you saying that mysql uses standard string comparison when comparing those datatypes?

Comment: Sure, why wouldn't they use string comparison when you give it a string? It's no different than `SELECT 'A' > 'B'` vs `SELECT 'A' < 'B'`

Comment: If you use columns instead of strings, *and* if those columns are `DATE`/`DATETIME`/`TIMESTAMP`, it'll work fine. If the columns are, say, `VARCHAR` you'll have this same issue.

Comment: yes I just created a temp table and tried it and you're right.  thanks for the explanation!  I wrongly assumed that mysql was somehow automagically parsing those strings into their respective data types.

Comment: @ceejayoz I think I'm still a bit confused about what happens when you compare a string to date or datetime like this: `SELECT CAST('2018-01-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) > '2018-01-01'`.  How is that evaluated?

Comment: That you'd have to test, I'm not sure how it'll evaluate it. It may cast the `DATETIME` to a string, or it may attempt to cast the string. I know it'll automatically cast something like `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE this_is_a_datetime>'2017-01-01'` without issues, because it knows the column's a `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those aren't dates, they're strings - you might as well be running `SELECT 'A' > 'B'`. Convert them to `DATE`s:

```
SELECT CAST('2018-01-01 00:00:00' AS DATE) > CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE)
```

or to `DATETIME`s:

```
SELECT CAST('2018-01-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) > CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATETIME)
```

Casting isn't necessary if you're comparing native MySQL dates coming from a `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP` column - MySQL knows what to do with those. It's only an issue here because you've given it raw strings.

Comment: Ahh I see now.  I was assuming that the same would hold true for date and datetime type comparison but it doesn't.  `SELECT CAST('2018-01-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) > CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE)` evaluates as `0` which is what I would expect and assumed was already happening in my example in the question.

Comment: For `DATE` you can simply do `SELECT DATE('2018-01-01 00:00:00') > DATE('2018-01-01')` (I tried it, maybe in previous versions of MySQL it doesn't work)